# How to handle massive transaction on huge service(like amazon)?

Tags: database

Let's assume there is an item.

It is sold by 100 users every second.

Describe one cycle transaction.

1. Amazon checks its stock. (10ms)
2. If an available request to card company for payment. (50ms)
3. Update item's stock. (50ms)

110ms(I decided arbitrarily) was consumed on one purchase.

How to handle this on amazon?
Is there one database on large services?
Is there a queue?

Just curiosity, Short answers or keywords are fine. thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['e-Commerce' scalable database model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580244/e-commerce-scalable-database-model)

Comment: @Martheen I think that question's answer handles just two keywords SQL, NoSQL.
I want little more than that.

Comment: Pretty much the only keyword is "scalability"

Comment: @Martheen thank you dude. I search with 'ebay database scalability'.
I find one powerpoint, this is pretty much detail.
Thank you